# Comparing solutions of higher order polynomial with a lower order polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let $P(\epsilon)$ is polynomial of order $N$ and $Q(\epsilon)$ is a polynomial of order $n$, where $N=n\times$integer. Is there any relation with the solutions of $Q(\epsilon)$ and $P(\epsilon)$? Is there any proof for that? Thanks

Comment: No, a relation between degrees does not constrain the coefficients of $P$ and $Q$, so there is expected to be no relation between the roots of $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: You are welcome. Since your question has been answered, I request you to close this question, by accepting the below answer. You can choose to wait, but by the looks of it, you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "proof" that there is no relation, take $P = x^4$ and $Q = x^2 - 4$ as a counterexample.